# JavaScript set date to beginning of x

Tags: javascript, datetime

Im working on a fn that will set the date to the beginning of the minute/hour/day/week/month/quarter/year.

I've got a start with the week doing something like:

```
var date = new Date(),
    day = d.getDay(),
    // adjust when day is sunday
    diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6 : 1);

    var updatedDate = new Date(date.setDate(diff);
```

but I have to wonder if there is a better way ( or framework ) to accomplish this type of thing?

Comment: Consider timezones (and the effect of crossing them) before implementing this further.

Comment: Where is `d` getting assigned a value?

Comment: You know you can just pass in zeros to anyone of these `new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);`

Comment: @adeneo but don't pass zero for `day`...

Comment: @adeneo i knew it was was easier than i was making it to be

Comment: @Alnitak - wouldn't that just get you Sunday *:goes to try it out:* ?

Comment: @adeneo No, because `day` is day of the month, not day of the week.

Comment: @amcdnl "day of the week" is probably the hardest of all, it's the only one for which there isn't a `setFoo()` method.

Comment: @Alnitak - Jeeze, I knew that, just totally missed the point !

Comment: @adeneo the hardest part of this is probably finding a nice way to specify the interval to round down to.

Comment: @amcdni what day do you consider to be the start of the week?  Your code above suggests Monday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best that I've been able to come up with so far:

```
function beginningOf(period, date) {
    date = new Date(date.valueOf()); // copy date

    if (period === "year" || period == "quarter") {
        date.setMonth(period === "quarter"
                      ? 3 * Math.floor(date.getMonth() / 3)
                      : 0);
        period = "month"; // now round down to the start of this month
    }

    if (period === "month" || period === "week") {
        date.setDate(period === "week"
                     ? date.getDate() - date.getDay() // Sunday is the first day, adjust to suit
                     : 1);
        period = "day"; // now round dow to the start of this day
    }

    // intentional switch fall-through
    switch (period) {
        case "day":
            date.setHours(0);
        case "hour":
            date.setMinutes(0);
        case "minute":
            date.setSeconds(0);
            date.setMilliseconds(0);
    }

    return date;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/6hj9u/

It's a slightly harder problem than I had expected...